# need matlab code for M-QAM modulation,demodulation implementation without toolbox

Tags: communication, matlab

up until now i only know how to implement M-QAM with the help of matlab toolbox, however is there any kind soul who can share modulation and demodulation code without the use of communication toolbox from matlab? i tried writing in function, however i only know how to used "if/else loop" to implement which does not suit M-QAM where my M is a variable value.

Comment: I don't know anything about the subject, but did you [search the File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14809-m-qam-modulation-and-demodulation)? And have you looked at the code used by the Matlab functions in question?

Comment: maybe you should try to find help here: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: its a rectangluar qam with Es=1 that i am trying to implement here, i tried to search for many file exchange yet i cant really find a file regarding modulation/demodulation that is able to fit in M-QAM, defined numbers amount of QAM are easier to find and implement but for M being a variable integer, its hard to implement. so i hope if there is any kind soul who knows and is able to help. thank you

Comment: but nobody would just provide you any ready code, in none of the stackexchange sites. That's not how it works here. If you don't want to use the toolboxes you need to study some theory, try to implement it by yourself and when you get stuck while programming, you can ask questions here. If you get stuck understanding the theory you rather ask at dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: i understand the theory towards modulation and demodulation, however i only know know how to write code specifically for like 2-qam 4-qam, where M is fixed and my code gets very long and ridiculous without the use of toolbox, i cant get seems to get any slightest information or hint on how i can try to change it to a M-QAM where the number is not fixed, writing matlab function for modulation for my level is only capable at a fixed M variable, that is why i am seeking help here

Comment: Maybe you can share a simple version of how you tried implementing the fixed M version and ask specific questions on how to generalize certain aspects of it. Or, if your fixed M code is very complicated, maybe at first ask question on how to simplify individual sections. **But** do not copy/paste all your code here and just say: please simplify. Be specific.

Comment: my codes comes with if/else loop function file and a normal file to run that function file and i had to do all the calculation manually then i would implement down with using of random binary to decimal then i call the function to the respective random decimal.
therefore my way of doing is very very fixed,long and ridiculous to a value of QAM

Comment: thank you daniel but is there like any websites that u can reference me to for me to get more details, because i have no knowledge regarding graycode, as graycode seems very advances to me in creating these modulation therefore i only used very simple matlab codings.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment, but posting this as a comment will break up the format.

Some code fragments which may help you to implement a coding scheme:

```
%Codes per axis (Graycode recommended)
code1=[0,1,3,2]
code2=[0,1,3,2]
%Create coding matrix
C = bsxfun(@plus,code1',(code2.*numel(code1)))
```

Which creates exactly the example shown on Wikipedia: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:16QAM_Gray_Coded.svg

I think this is the most tricky part of rectangle QAM, try implementing the Graycode and de- and encoding on your own.